# Parsing numbers with double.TryParse strange behaviour

Tags: c#, parsing

Why would `double.TryParse()` with these settings not parse

```
double.TryParse("1.035,00",
NumberStyles.AllowCurrencySymbol | NumberStyles.AllowLeadingWhite | NumberStyles.AllowTrailingWhite |
NumberStyles.AllowDecimalPoint | NumberStyles.AllowLeadingSign,
GlobalSettings.Instance.DefaultCulture, out price);
```

where `DefaultCulture` is sl-SI (Slovenian), which has the dot `.` as digit grouping symbol and , as decimal point. The `price` remains `0` after the parse.

?

Comment: TryParse returns a `bool` that indicates if parsing the value succeeded or failed. For your example, TryParse returns `false`. So the cause for `price` being `0` is that the string couldn't be parsed.

Comment: I find it strange that some would vote close due to localization. If the problem was the culture then it would affect numerous cultures, all those that used comma as decimal separator, which is both the ISO standard and the representation used in most countries

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are missing `NumberStyles.AllowThousands`:

```
double.TryParse("1.035,00", NumberStyles.AllowCurrencySymbol | 
                            NumberStyles.AllowLeadingWhite | 
                            NumberStyles.AllowTrailingWhite |
                            NumberStyles.AllowDecimalPoint | 
                            NumberStyles.AllowLeadingSign | 
                            NumberStyles.AllowThousands,
                            GlobalSettings.Instance.DefaultCulture, out price);
```

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me

```
double.TryParse("1.035,00",
NumberStyles.Any,
GlobalSettings.Instance.DefaultCulture, out price);
```

Comment: would anyone else advise on using NumberStyles.Any in a sense, if there are any potential problems with it?

Comment: As per MSDN **Indicates that all styles except AllowHexSpecifier are used. This is a composite number style.**